# song collection

Tags: windows-phone-7

I hope to use codes to create a sound collection and play the music sequentially.
Users can add and remove a song from/to the collection.

But I noticed that 'On Wp7, you can not create a SongCoLlection object youself, you must always obtain an immutable SongCollection from one of the other class(such as album).

Is there a way to let user edit song collection in an app?
(which is very simple on ios)

Welcome any comment

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This depends on what you are trying to achieve.

If you want to write an application that makes changes to the users Music Library, this is not possible. The WP7 APIs give you access to contacts, music library, pictures - but only provide read-only access (except in the case of pictures where you can add new images). This is designed to protect the user's data, you wouldn't want a malicious or poorly crafted application deleting your data would you?

If you just want to create something local to your application, you could create your own SongCollection class, which is simply a list of songs, `List<Song>`.

Comment: I just hope to get all songs in music library and give the right to users selecting the songs in library, and adding the songs users selected to a list and play the sounds in the list sequently. It just read only, do not change anything of music library

Comment: @user262325 in that case, create a List<Song> - there is nothing terribly special about SongCollection!

Comment: @ColinE Playing music with `MediaPlayer.Play(song_list);` doesn't work because MediaPlayer.Play is expecting a SongCollection. What can I do?